# Cannot install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (64-bit)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying to install vs rd2015 but for some reason, the installer fails everytime with this log:

```
    [0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\Octavian\Downloads\vc_redist.x64.exe, cmdline: ''
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Octavian\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20160525122812.log'
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Octavian\Downloads\vc_redist.x64.exe'
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\Octavian\Downloads\'
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - 14.0.23918'
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:12]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Install
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Octavian\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20160525122812_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log'
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Octavian\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20160525122812_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Octavian\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20160525122812_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log'
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Octavian\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20160525122812_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:15]i300: Apply begin
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:16]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:16]i361: Created a system restore point.
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:16]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{dab68466-3a7d-41a8-a5cf-415e3ff8ef71}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\Octavian\AppData\Local\Temp\{dab68466-3a7d-41a8-a5cf-415e3ff8ef71}\.be\VC_redist.x64.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{dab68466-3a7d-41a8-a5cf-415e3ff8ef71}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {dab68466-3a7d-41a8-a5cf-415e3ff8ef71}, version: 14.0.23918.0
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{dab68466-3a7d-41a8-a5cf-415e3ff8ef71}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[13A4:1430][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.
[13A4:1430][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7B50D081-E670-3B43-A460-0E2CDB5CE984}v14.0.23918\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
[13A4:1430][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i304: Verified existing payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503.
[13A4:1430][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7B50D081-E670-3B43-A460-0E2CDB5CE984}v14.0.23918\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
[13A4:1430][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.
[13A4:1430][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DFFEB619-5455-3697-B145-243D936DB95B}v14.0.23918\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
[13A4:1430][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i304: Verified existing payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92.
[13A4:1430][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DFFEB619-5455-3697-B145-243D936DB95B}v14.0.23918\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
[13A4:1430][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows81_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows81_x64.
[13A4:1430][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i305: Verified acquired payload: Windows81_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows81_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:17]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7B50D081-E670-3B43-A460-0E2CDB5CE984}v14.0.23918\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:18]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:18]i325: Registering dependency: {dab68466-3a7d-41a8-a5cf-415e3ff8ef71} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:18]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{DFFEB619-5455-3697-B145-243D936DB95B}v14.0.23918\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:18]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:18]i325: Registering dependency: {dab68466-3a7d-41a8-a5cf-415e3ff8ef71} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:18]i301: Applying execute package: Windows81_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:20]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:20]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:20]i319: Applied execute package: Windows81_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:20]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:20]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{dab68466-3a7d-41a8-a5cf-415e3ff8ef71}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[13A4:0CDC][2016-05-25T12:28:20]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{dab68466-3a7d-41a8-a5cf-415e3ff8ef71}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0854:1850][2016-05-25T12:28:20]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

The links to the to the installers are from here:

https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0dll-is-missing-f2702.html

As you can see, I'm trying to resolve the "The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing" problem in the first place.

Any help would be much appreciated)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue by following these instuctions:

You can find the Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu at below.

C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\469A82B09E217DDCF849181A586DF1C97C0C5C85\packages\Patch\amd64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu

copy this file to a folder you like, and

> wusa.exe Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu /extract:XXXX
>
> DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:XXXX\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.cab
>
> vc_redist.x64.exe /repair