# RStudio on Windows 2012 R2 cannot work without VC++ 2015 but it will not install

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, rstudio, windows-server-2012-r2, system-administration

I have all updates on my installation of Windows 2012 R2 but for some reason none of the solutions suggested work. I require `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` to run RStudio, unfortunately, I have no way to get it running & I tried every solution proposed.

The exact problem is described in [Cannot install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (64-bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433118/cannot-install-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2015-64-bit)

The expected result is VC++ 2015 to be installed & RStudio to run.

Attempts to manually apply those solutions didn't avail:

[image]

Log file result from installation of VC++ 2015:

```
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i001: Burn v3.10.4.4718, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Windows\Temp\{9F7F6448-26EA-488F-B797-D9C4ED9535A9}\.cr\VC_redist.x64.exe
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\VC_redist.x64.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=308 -burn.filehandle.self=316'
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\'
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20230107020512.log'
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.34.31931'
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[10E4:12B4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '14.34.31931.0'
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i100: Detect begin, 11 packages
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i000: Setting string variable 'Arm64_Check' to value 'AMD64'
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i102: Detected related bundle: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.0.23026.0, operation: MajorUpgrade
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i103: Detected related package: {0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.0.23026.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i103: Detected related package: {BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.0.23026.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i103: Detected related package: {0D3E9E15-DE7A-300B-96F1-B4AF12B96488}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.0.23026.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i103: Detected related package: {BC958BD2-5DAC-3862-BB1A-C1BE0790438D}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.0.23026.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i101: Detected package: vcRuntime_arm64, state: Absent, cached: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.1' evaluates to true.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:12]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[10E4:12B4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i200: Plan begin, 11 packages, action: Install
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64) AND NOT (Arm64_Check = "ARM64")' evaluates to true.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20230107020512_001_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log'
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20230107020512_001_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64) AND NOT (Arm64_Check = "ARM64")' evaluates to true.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20230107020512_002_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log'
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20230107020512_002_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i052: Condition 'Arm64_Check = "ARM64"' evaluates to false.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i201: Planned package: vcRuntime_arm64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i207: Planned related bundle: {e46eca4f-393b-40df-9f49-076faf788d83}, type: Upgrade, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, dependency: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i300: Apply begin
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:05:17]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i362: System restore disabled, system restore point not created.
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d4cecf3b-b68f-4995-8840-52ea0fab646e}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Windows\Temp\{24898943-C62B-411E-A84F-E9DEA6A59B2E}\.be\VC_redist.x64.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{d4cecf3b-b68f-4995-8840-52ea0fab646e}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: VC,redist.x64,amd64,14.34,bundle, version: 14.34.31931.0
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d4cecf3b-b68f-4995-8840-52ea0fab646e}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0C20:0A88][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i305: Verified acquired payload: Windows81_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows81_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
[0C20:0A88][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{CF4C347D-954E-4543-88D2-EC17F07F466F}v14.34.31931\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
[0C20:0A88][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{CF4C347D-954E-4543-88D2-EC17F07F466F}v14.34.31931\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
[0C20:0A88][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{EAE242B1-0A26-485A-BFEB-0292EE9F03CB}v14.34.31931\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
[0C20:0A88][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{EAE242B1-0A26-485A-BFEB-0292EE9F03CB}v14.34.31931\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:05:18]i301: Applying execute package: Windows81_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3ACBF3890FC9C8A6F3D2155ECF106028E5F55164\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:07:40]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:07:40]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:07:40]i319: Applied execute package: Windows81_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:07:40]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:07:40]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d4cecf3b-b68f-4995-8840-52ea0fab646e}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:07:40]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: VC,redist.x64,amd64,14.34,bundle
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:07:40]i352: Removing cached bundle: {d4cecf3b-b68f-4995-8840-52ea0fab646e}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{d4cecf3b-b68f-4995-8840-52ea0fab646e}\
[0C20:0EE0][2023-01-07T02:07:40]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d4cecf3b-b68f-4995-8840-52ea0fab646e}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[10E4:11E4][2023-01-07T02:07:41]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: I don't believe the IDE would work on such an old installation.

Comment: This isn't a solution, but I just ended up copying the correct DLLs from a functional Windows Server 2012 R2 system with VC++ 2015 installed. It may be time to retire this OS as it is a becoming time sink...